# Google Cloud Platform - Stack Driver Enabled - 100% Compute Errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I developed and support a client's mobile app that uses Firebase services.

Google Cloud Platform logged this event yesterday at 4:17 am:

```
'<my account email> has executed
google.api.serviceusage.v1.ServiceUsage.EnableService
on stackdriver.googleapis.com'
```

I was sleeping at the time and a review of Google Admin Console Login Audit Log does not show a login event around that same time.

Immediately, 100% errors were reporting for 'compute':

[image]

A look at the Stackdriver API overview page does not give any indication of activity:

[image]

My question, my concern, how/why did this service get activated and what is the activity driving the compute errors at 100%?

During my efforts to understand, I clicked on Compute Engine API in the API library, which enabled the API (but no VMs, Disk, etc. were created):

[image]

A short time later, Google Cloud Platform has several log entries:

google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.CloudBuild.ListBuilds
was executed on builds

Number of returned items 1000

The 'compute' errors stopped.

When I disabled the Compute Engine API, the ListBuilds logs stopped, but the Computer Errors returned to 100%.

Comment: You can check the logs under [cloud logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#getting_started) to have a better view on the issue.

Comment: A number of Google services depend on Compute Engine. If you disable the service, you will see errors. For example, Cloud Build runs on VMs (Compute Engine instances).

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a definitive answer to my question.

It's clear that Stackdriver API was enabled, but I don't know why.

[image: Stackdriver Enabled]

When enabled, 100% Compute errors were being reported (orange line on graph) without any details.

[image: Compute Erros]

While customizing the Google Cloud Platform Dashboard for this account, I toggled/enabled the Compute Engine card/graph hoping that might reveal some clues regarding the 100% errors. That action initialized the Compute Engine API. Almost immediately the Compute errors ended but there was a surge of activity that has continued. Reviewing many resources I found information that suggest this is normal behavior.

[image: Anonymous Activity]

I would still like to fully understand how Stackdriver was enabled, why it was enabled, what value it provides, if I can simply disable it and Compute API as this project will never require VM compute services.